# Merge duplicated pandas rows on specific rules

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['1', '2', None], 
    'name': ['Tom', 'Peter', 'Peter'], 
    'registered': [True, False, True]
})
```

the ultimate goal is to merge the data frame grouped by the name and according to certain rules, e.g.

- if one of the duplicated `identifier` is a string and the other is `None`, then use the string `identifier`
- do a logical `or` to all `registered` entries

So the result should look like

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['1', '2'], 
    'name': ['Tom', 'Peter'], 
    'registered': [True, True]
})
```

I tried it with `groupby`, but maybe this is the wrong way at all?

[`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) do not let me to add specific rules.

Comment: Would you please also post the python code you have written so far?

Comment: `df.groupby('name').agg({'identifier' : 'first', 'registered' : any})`?

Comment: Huh...  slap on a `sort_values` call first... `df.sort_values(['identifier']).groupby('name').agg({'identifier' : 'first', 'registered' : any})`

Comment: So, `sort_values` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom function with `dropna`, `drop_duplicates` and `any`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['1', '2', None, '2'], 
    'name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'], 
    'registered': [True, False, True, True]
})
print (df)
  identifier   name  registered
0          1  Peter        True
1          2  Peter       False
2       None  Peter        True
3          2  Peter        True

def f(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'identifier': x['identifier'].dropna().drop_duplicates(), 
                         'registered': x['registered'].any()})

df = df.groupby('name').apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
    name identifier  registered
0  Peter          1        True
1  Peter          2        True
```

Comment: Hm... check your output...? You should get just one row.

Comment: Hmmm, I think not, it depends what OP need - if first non `NaN` value or if all unique non `NaN`s values.

Comment: Fair point. OP needs to clarify... although I would think it foolish if the same person has multiple identifiers... but that's OP's headache :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's modify your data slightly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['1', None, '2'], 
    'name': ['Tom', 'Peter', 'Peter'], 
    'registered': [True, False, True]
})

df

  identifier   name  registered
0          1    Tom        True
1       None  Peter       False
2          2  Peter        True
```

A "None" is the first identifier for "Peter". You can remedy this with a `sort_values` call, following which, you call `groupby` + `agg`.

```
df.sort_values(['identifier'])\
  .groupby('name', as_index=False)\
  .agg({'identifier' : 'first', 'registered' : any})

    name  registered identifier
0  Peter        True          2
1    Tom        True          1
```